# 2x4 as floor joists?

Tags: wood, code-compliance, joists, construction

I have a 5'x5' former elevator shaft. I would like to convert the available space to closets and so I need to install a floor and a ceiling.

I'd like to use 2x4 and I was trying to use [this table](https://www.mycarpentry.com/joist-span-table.html) to determine the required spacing, but the table only goes down to 2x6.

So, question: Is it OK to use 2x4 and what is the maximal allowed spacing? (The species is whatever Home Depot carries in the North East.)

Comment: How deep do you fall if the floor gives?  2x4 would probably hold a thin person at 5 feet(no jumping).  2x6 is much safer(can jump).  Ceiling can be 2x4s, unless someone else is above and jumping.  2x6s probably minimum for code.

Comment: It depends, in part, on the span.  If you are only spanning 4-5 feet then 2x4s *might* be OK.  Much longer, though, and you probably need a heavier piece.

Comment: I would not use 2X4s. My rule of thumb is up to 4 ft span, use 2x4s, up to 6 ft span use 2X6s. 8 ft span, 2X8s

Comment: 2x4 floor framing is almost unheard of. Can you detail why you want this? Is it a question of spacing? Cost? Attachment?